# How do I run multiple instances of SQL Workbench on Windows?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I use SQL workbench (not mysql-workbench) to connect to Redshift clusters. I might need to query tables from different clusters at the same time. Since one instance can only be connected to a single cluster at a time, I'm looking for a way to open multiple instances of the application.

Comment: Windows Sandbox might actually be your solution.  Are you using Windows 10 version 1903?

Answer (score 5):

In case someone should need an answer to this, in MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE by default only 1 instance will open.  To allow more than one, there is a setting to allow this.  You can go to:  (MENU) EDIT --> (SUB-MENU) Preferences --> (LEFT SIDE MENU) Others --> (BOX) Others, then check the checkbox to "Allow more than one instance of MySQL Workbench to run".  I hope this helps someone!

Comment: This only works on Windows. A possible work-around on Mac would be opening the programm via a terminal command: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64705208/534883

Answer (score 2):

This link provide answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506299/using-multiple-instances-of-sql-workbench-j/69506495#69506495
You have the New Window option in File Menu. That option will be used to create another connection Tab.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers, instead quote the most important parts and provide the link as reference only.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1119707)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 32 bit version and 64 bit version.Both will open simultaneously.

Comment: What if he only had 64 bit, or his computer/device is 32 bit? If it was a 32 bit OS, you can't do it this way (because 32 bit OS don't support 64 bit). But if he only had the 64 bit program installed, then he can't open 32 bit program.

Comment: True, If your system is 64 bit and if you have both 64 and 32 bit executables you can go with this.